# How to build an index that is best for this SQL?

Tags: sql, database, indexing

I'm querying database by a simple SQL like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT label FROM Document WHERE folderId=123
```

I need a best index for it.

There are two way to implement this.

(1) create two indexes

```
CREATE INDEX .. ON Document (label)
CREATE INDEX .. ON Document (folderId)
```

(2) create a composite index:

```
CREATE INDEX .. ON Document (folderId, label)
```

According to the implementation of the database index. Which method is more reasonable? Thank you.

Comment: Is this your only use case? I.e Will your query always just be `WHERE folderId = ...` or will you be searching specifically for a label, like `WHERE label = '...'`?

Comment: I use MS SQL Server. And It's my only use case. I think the composite index is better. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second index -- the composite index -- is the best index for this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT label
FROM Document
WHERE folderId = 123;
```

First, the index covers the query so the data pages do not need to be accessed (in most databases).

The index works because the engine can seek to the records with the identified `folderId`.  The information on `label` can be pulled.  Most databases should use the index for pulling the distinct labels as well.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is useful. But my reputation is low.

Comment: @zzzsleeper . . . As the OP, you can accept this (or any other) answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends also on the used dbms. I'm not sure if all dbms support the use of multiple indexes.

I should think the combined index (folderid, label) is the best solution in your case as it is possible to build your result set solely by using index data. So it doesn't even need to access the real data. 
It can even be a strategy to add extra columns to an index so a query which is called a lot can be answered by only accessing the index.

Comment: I use MS SQL Server. Your answer is useful. But my reputation is low. Thank you.